# How to merge 2 rewrite rule using Apache mod_rewrite module in php

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I was wondering if i could merge 2 rewrite rules. I'm using the Apache mod_rewrite module.

rule #1

```
RewriteRule ^albums/singles/?$ discography/discography.php?primarytype=2 [L,QSA]
```

rule #2

```
RewriteRule ^albums/ep/?$ discography/discography.php?primarytype=3 [L,QSA]
```

Can i merge those 2 rules ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^albums/(singles|ep)/?$ discography/discography.php?primarytype=2 [L,QSA]
```

See if this works for you? I have not tested it right now.

The first part is the regex the second is the url that is to be rewritten to. So in second url i think this (2|3) might not work.

Actually you can capture the dynamic part of the url in RewriteCond and then use that as primarytype=$1

That is your result url can become primarytype=ep or primarytype=singles but it does not seem like they can be made 2 or 3 dynamically.

```
RewriteRule ^albums/(singles|ep)/?$ discography/discography.php?primarytype=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The above might be an option for you to generate the urls with primarytype=ep or primarytype=singles but it does not seem like 2 or 3 can be dynamically chosen like you have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ok let me check